# aws cli commands having difficulty with output formats

Tags: amazon-web-services, command, aws-cli

any help with this issue will be appreciated. running this command

```
$ aws ssm get-parameters --names /save-my-credentials/dbstring --profile iamadmin-general
```

Unknown output type: None

Thanks a million

Comment: The command by itself is fine. The issue must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Well the command works fine and do not have any output settable parameter. Can you try reconfiguring your profile?

```
aws configure --profile iamadmin-general
```

Then in the last step set Default output format: json

[image]

Comment: How come it never worked with just including the json format as part of the  $ aws configure ...  AWS Access Key ID [****************]: 888888888888886JOX
AWS Secret Access Key [****************]: 1rR3uuuuuuuuuuffffffff
Default region name [us-east-1]: us-east-1
Default output format [json]: json

Comment: but this aws configure --profile iamadmin-general                                                       
 AWS Access Key ID [****************]: 888888888888886JOX AWS Secret Access Key [****************]: 1rR3uuuuuuuuuuffffffff Default region name [us-east-1]: us-east-1 Default output format [json]: json

Answer (score 0):

You must have the `output = None` in your `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[profile iamadmin-general]
region = us-east-1
output = None
```

Either remove it or change to json (default) or table/text.

You can also specify output type right in the command by adding `--output=json` as an argument.